# Forgot password - Rescue Disk does not work

Tags: truecrypt

I have entire drive encrypted by TrueCrypt. What is sad is that I forgot my password since I changed it to a more complex one.
I have a Rescue Disc created with an old password.
Unfortunately, I'm not able to use it.
When Rescue Disk menu appears, I select 3 for Restore key data (volume header), then I type my password and then program ask me to confirm if I want to modify drive 0. I press y. From this point nothing happens. I'm not getting any confirmation for over an hour. It looks like program is not doing anything.
How can I decrypt my drive?

Comment: Format it, and restore from the backups that you regularly make?

Comment: I could do that but this would cause me to lose some of my data.

Comment: Sounds like you learned a valuable lesson to backup more often then

Comment: Ok, I'm going to brute-force my password :P. It's just 3 new characters compared to the old one.

Comment: I didn't come to this site for lessons. I know importance of data backup. I ask for help because I thik this is software (hardware?) error that I need to be fixed.

Comment: Unless I misunderstand the situation, you forgot your password and now you can't get to the encrypted data. That is the software and hardware working exactly the way it is supposed to.

Comment: Almost. Rescue Disk should be able to help as it was created with old password and I remember the old password. Instead, it freezes when I try do use it. I'm also not so sure that I actually forgot my password... Maybe some data is corrupted. I assumed that message "Incorrect password" means that I forgot the correct one but I was 99,99% sure that I remember it. Until now...

Comment: Also, the program freezes after using option "Restore TrueCrypt boot loader".

Comment: The whole purpose of Truecrypt is so NO ONE can get your data without the password, this includes YOU. Hell no there is no secret way to de-crypt it, if there was it would not be the best encryption technology on the planet and NO ONE would use it. What I would do, make an Image of the hard drive, maybe two. Do this before attempting anything else, now you have an exact copy or two of the drive, this way you can try some things on the hard drive if you think there is corruption or something other than not having the correct password.

Comment: I know the password! You don't seem to understand it ;/.

Comment: @EBGreen, Moab: According to http://www.truecrypt.org/docs/?s=rescue-disk (especially 3rd point) the rescue disk is able to decrypt the data using the old password. Strictly speaking, this is a security flaw which is why there's a warning about it, but it's possible to decrypt data with an *old* password (the password used for the rescue disk) indeed.

Answer (score 1):

You may have better luck booting the drive on a different hardware setup or approaching the task from a different direction.

Certain BIOSes prevent TrueCrypt from functioning properly (or, rather, TrueCrypt authors do not have the resources to make TrueCrypt function properly on all BIOSes). So a couple of things to try:

- Try moving the disk into a different computer;
- Try booting it in a virtual machine (e.g. VmWare Workstation) that permits booting off real hard drives.
- Boot another operating system, install TrueCrypt on it, and then train Volume Tools onto your encrypted partition to restore the header from either internal volume copy or external header backup.

Answer (score -4):

Use a Linux distribution and you may see your data again!
Yes, Many programs on Windows OS I used before like "Fake folder and Lockdir" , the content they encrypt when I use Linux I can see them normally.
Good luck...

Comment: No, you are talking about something entirely different. What you are referring to is basically taking a secret note and putting it in into a safe. Now, you must have a key to open the safe and read the note, but you might as well drill a hole in the safe and retrieve the note and then read it. With TrueCrypt the analogy would be taking a note and replacing every letter in it, say, with a letter that is 13 places down in the alphabet from the letter you are replacing and then destroying the original. So now, without knowing the shift distance it is impossible to restore the original text.